# Google Workspace 'viewer/reader' role

Tags: identity, google-workspace, audit, google-iam

I am wondering if there is any pre-defined role that would grant full reader/viewer access to the Google Workspace admin portal, allowing me to check all users, security settings, etc. (Important that it should be read only access)

If such a role does not exist, which roles should I add to a custom role for this purpose, applying the principle of least privilege?

Looked for roles in google documentation but not much help.

Comment: The information you are looking for is in this [document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986?hl=en) and this [document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2406043)

Comment: @JohnHanley if you have an answer to the question, please post it as an answer :)